# Maintain Plotly chart state after callback to Python capturing data

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, plotly, state, streamlit

I'm running the code from the tutorial [here](https://dev.to/andfanilo/streamlit-components-scatterplot-with-selection-using-plotly-js-3d7n). (NOTE: The code in the text of the tutorial does not work right, but [the companion code in Git](https://github.com/andfanilo/streamlit_scatterplot_selection), which is what I'm using, works fine.)

The code is so you can use Python Streamlit to create an interactive Plotly chart, and then Python's `__init__.py` can capture what the user selects from the chart.

The code works - **however after a  selection event on the Plotly chart, after the data has been returned to Python, Streamlit runs the entire `__init__.py` again, which causes the chart to revert to a fresh chart** losing any annotation, drawn lines, zooming-in, Etc.

This is a problem because, for example, if a user zooms in to get to the data needed, and maybe draws something on the chart, if they make a selection ... the zoom and drawing are lost because the chart refreshes from scratch.

As an aside, **I have found [This (state management)](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js#state-management)** but since I'm hacking my way through tutorials, I have no idea how to implement this correctly (when I try, I get a lot of errors about the variables - data: [], layout: {}, frames: [], config: {} - not being declared properly.)

This is the complete code...

***__init__.py***

```
    import json
    import os
    import random

    import random
    import plotly.express as px
    import streamlit as st

    import plotly.utils
    import streamlit.components.v1 as components

    _component_func = components.declare_component(
        "streamlit_scatterplot_selection",
        url="http://localhost:3001",
    )

    def st_scatterplot(fig, key="st_plotly"):
        spec = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
        selected_points = _component_func(spec=spec, default=[], key=key)
        return selected_points


    @st.cache
    def random_data():
        return random.sample(range(100), 50), random.sample(range(100), 50)

    st.subheader("Plotly interactive scatterplot")
    x, y = random_data()
    fig = px.scatter(x=x, y=y, title="My fancy plot")
    v = st_scatterplot(fig)
    st.write(v)
```

***PlotlyScatterplot.tsx***

```
import React from "react"
import {
  withStreamlitConnection,
  Streamlit,
  ComponentProps,
} from "streamlit-component-lib"
import Plot from "react-plotly.js"

const PlotlyScatterplot = (props: ComponentProps) => {

  const { data, layout, frames, config } = JSON.parse(props.args.spec)

  const handleSelected = function (eventData: any) {
    Streamlit.setComponentValue(
      eventData.points.map((p: any) => {
        return { index: p.pointIndex, x: p.x, y: p.y }
      })
    )
  }

  return (
    <Plot
      data={data}
      layout={layout}
      frames={frames}
      config={config}
      revision={0}
      onSelected={handleSelected}
      onInitialized={() => Streamlit.setFrameHeight()}
    />
  )
}

export default withStreamlitConnection(PlotlyScatterplot)
```

***index.tsx***

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import PlotlyScatterplot from "./PlotlyScatterplot2"

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <PlotlyScatterplot />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

***react-app-env.d.ts***

```
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. The answer is; there's a (as far as I can tell) undocumented parameter in the
`Plot` from `react-plotly.js` called `uirevision`. If set to `True`, this allows the chart annotations (zoom, lines drawn, selected points, Etc.) to persist.

To implement it...

In order to get the results back to streamlit from the plotly chart, I modified the code I found at [streamlit-ploty-events](https://github.com/yihui-he/streamlit-plotly-events)

My structure looks like this.

```
streamlit_root/
    |--pages/
        |--control_charts.py
    |--react/
        |--control_charts/ <-Just an arbitrary directory name matching my python filename. Strictly for organizational reasons. 
            |--frontend
                |--package.json
                |--package-lock.json
                |--tsconfig.json
                |--src
                    |--index.tsx
                    |--react-app-env.d.ts
                    |--StreamlitPlotlyEventsCapture.tsx
```

Most of this all came straight from [streamlit-ploty-events](https://github.com/yihui-he/streamlit-plotly-events), with the exception that the code that she had in the `__init__.py`, I moved to my `control_charts.py` file.

The following files are are identical to what I downloaded from [streamlit-ploty-events](https://github.com/yihui-he/streamlit-plotly-events)...

- streamlit_root/react/frontend/package.json
- streamlit_root/react/frontend/package-lock.json
- streamlit_root/react/frontend/tsconfig.json
- streamlit_root/react/frontend/src/react-app-env.d.ts

I changed the `streamlit_root/react/frontend/src/index.tsx` so I could rename the class (not necessary to change the class name)

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import StreamlitPlotlyEventsCapture from "./StreamlitPlotlyEventsCapture" //this is my tsx file name

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StreamlitPlotlyEventsCapture /> // only changed the name to match the classname in ./StreamlitPlotlyEventsCapture.tsx
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

The `StreamlitPlotlyEventsCapture.tsx` got modded so I could control what data I wanted sent back. This was interesting for a number of reasons.

1. Anything you pass into the parameter `custom_data_columns` when you create the plotly `figure` can be easily drawn out via the Typescript code (react.) It was easier for me to pass in exactly what I wanted to get out (via the python fig using custom_data_columns) than to parse the `data` variable.
2. There's a big caveat here. The `custom_data_columns` is a list (immutable in python) and the order of that list *remains* inside the react code (the StreamlitPlotlyEventsCapture.tsx.) However, if you try to pass the entire `custom_data_columns` list back to python (streamlit) it screws up the ordering, and the list order is different everytime.

***So you have to parse the elements out of the list `custom_data_columns` within the react code.***

This is what my `StreamlitPlotlyEventsCapture.tsx` looks like...

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react"
import {
      StreamlitComponentBase,
      withStreamlitConnection,
      Streamlit,
//    ComponentProps,
} from "streamlit-component-lib"
import Plot from "react-plotly.js"

class StreamlitPlotlyEventsCapture extends StreamlitComponentBase {
  public render = (): ReactNode => {
    // Pull Plotly object from args and parse
    const plot_obj = JSON.parse(this.props.args["plot_obj"]);
    const override_height = this.props.args["override_height"];
    const override_width = this.props.args["override_width"];

    // Event booleans
    const click_event = this.props.args["click_event"];
    const select_event = this.props.args["select_event"];
    const hover_event = this.props.args["hover_event"];

    Streamlit.setFrameHeight(override_height);
    return (
      <Plot
        data={plot_obj.data}
        layout={plot_obj.layout}
        config={plot_obj.config}
        frames={plot_obj.frames}
        onClick={click_event ? this.plotlyEventHandler : function(){}}
        onSelected={select_event ? this.plotlyEventHandler : function(){}}
        onHover={hover_event ? this.plotlyEventHandler : function(){}}
        style={{width: override_width, height: override_height}}
        className="stPlotlyChart"
      />
    )
  }

  /** Click handler for plot. */
  private plotlyEventHandler = (data: any) => {
    // Build array of points to return
    var clickedPoints: Array<any> = [];
    // The following line used with util.inspect(arrayItem) below
    //const util = require('util')

    /* I dont know why we can't directly use "this.variables" in the clickedPoints.push
       but we can't, so we create the variables here. */
    var wasClicked  = this.props.args["click_event"];
    var wasSelected = this.props.args["select_event"];
    var wasHovered  = this.props.args["hover_event"];
    
    data.points.forEach(function (arrayItem: any) {
      /* Below line will dump out the full contents of each array to the browser console
         REALLY slows things down. Troubleshooting only
         Needs const util from above. */
      //console.log(util.inspect(arrayItem, {maxArrayLength: null, depth:null }))
      clickedPoints.push({  
        // I dont know why we can't directly use "this.variables" here, but we can't 
        // so we use the variables created above. 
        clicked:wasClicked,
        selected:wasSelected,
        hovered:wasHovered,
        x: arrayItem.x,
        y: arrayItem.y,
        // curveNumber: arrayItem.curveNumber,
        // pointNumber: arrayItem.pointNumber,
        //pointIndex: arrayItem.pointIndex, 
        /* customdata comes from what is set for the "hover" by line...
            fig = px.scatter(df, [...], custom_data = hover_column_names)  
        ...in ../lib/plotting_tools/charts.py */
        selected_xcol: arrayItem.customdata[9],
        xvalue: arrayItem.customdata[3],
        selected_ycol: arrayItem.customdata[10],
        yvalue: arrayItem.customdata[2],
        /* customdata only maintains it's immutable order within the Typescript
        If you return ALL of 'arrayItem.customdata', the order is mangled beween 
        restarts of streamlit, so you'll never know the right element number 
        to select after it gets back to python */
        // 7th item in the customdata passed to the figure!!
        injection_id: arrayItem.customdata[7] 
      })
    });

    // Return array as JSON to Streamlit
    Streamlit.setComponentValue(JSON.stringify(clickedPoints))
  }
}

export default withStreamlitConnection(StreamlitPlotlyEventsCapture)
```

**NOTE: that I'm using `arrayItem.customdata[3]` to pass the data back out.** The third element in the array (`arrayItem.customdata[3]`) in react is the same third element from `custom_data_columns` (I.e. `custom_data_columns[3]`. However, again, if you tried to pass out all of the data with something like `returnedcustomdatalist: arrayItem.customdata` the list you would get in Python (`returnedcustomdatalist`) would be out of order and number 3 coming out would not be the same as the number 3 you passed in (meaning it's useless.)

The only other file you need is a python file (`__init__.py` or any other file. I used `control_charts.py`.

(The important parts of) my control charts looks like this ...

```
import plotly.express as px
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components
import json

fig = px.scatter( df, # A pandas DataFrame
                  x=x_column_name, # The string name of the column to form the x-axis of the plotly chart
                  y=y_column_name, # The string name of the column to form the x-axis of the plotly chart
                  color=df[color_column_name], # A Pandas series. 'color_column_name' is the string name of the column to form the color legend. In this case different from either x or y
                  width=chart_width, 
                  labels={ # Axis lables on the chart
                      "x": x_column_name,
                      "y": y_column_name,
                      color_column_name: "Compounds"
                  },
                  custom_data = custom_data_columns # A python list containing the string names of the columns I want returned to streamlit from plotly by react.
                 )

height = 300 # Scatter plots height
width  = 600 # Scatter plots width
key    = "MyStreamlitScatterPLotConsistentKey" # Necessary so streamlit keeps talking to the same chart

# This uses streamlit components to attach to the StreamlitPlotlyEventsCapture class in ./StreamlitPlotlyEventsCapture.tsx
_component_func = components.declare_component(
   "streamlit_scatterplot_selection",
   url="http://{}:3001".format(nodejsip),
)        

#===========================================================================
# To pass the configuration to the chart:
# So, the figure has to be converted to a JSON/dict object, which will be passed to react
#===========================================================================

# Convert the fig to a serialized JSON object.        
spec = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

# Convert to a python dict for manipulation. Thsi is so you can add configuration items like the UIrevision below
spec_dict = json.loads(spec)

# Add to dict to enable uirevision which will help the chart persist after data is selected
# otherwise it keeps reloading from svcratch
spec_dict["layout"]["uirevision"] = True

# Dump back to a serialized JSON object
fig_json = json.dumps(spec_dict, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

# kwargs will be exposed to frontend in "args"
component_value = _component_func(
   plot_obj=fig_json,
   override_height=height,
   override_width=width,
   key=key,
   click_event=click_event, # True or False which enables or disables the users ability to click and have data returned
   select_event=select_event, # True or False which enables or disables the users ability to group select and have data returned
   hover_event=hover_event, # True or False which enables or disables the users ability to hover and have data returned
   default="[]",  # Default return empty JSON list
)

# Parse component_value since it's JSON and return to Streamlit
returned_data = json.loads(component_value) # JSON object
```

So, finally, for all this to be able to work - you need to BOTH run the react server (in this case, you can also point to the react build dir, but this is for development) and then run the control_charts.py with streamlit.

I.e. (In a terminal)

```
cd streamlit_root/react/frontend/
npm install 
npm run start
```

Leave that running. And in ANOTHER terminal...

```
cd streamlit_root/pages
streamlit run control_charts.py
```

Good luck!

- This code is not tested, since it was cut and pasted from a much, much larger codebase. YOu may have to dink with it.
- I had some error messages due to compatibility issues between different version of NPM. YOU're better off just google'ing the error messages and taking the advice you find if you run into this. Thats what I did.

Comment: Hi Mr. RightmireM,  I have a similar issue with Streamlit_Plotly scatter plots.  I need to read the state of a Plotly Scatter plot after it is rendered by Streamlit and the user has clicked on the legend to select (show) or deselect (hide) traces.  I need to get final plot states (with selected or deselected traces) to render the plots as png or gif images, so the images can be read into the FPDF (reporting) package to include in a PDF report.   Which specific "__init__.py" file did you modify? In Streamlit or Plotly, and in which Python subpackage or module?

Comment: Hey @RichLysakowskiPhD
So, the `__init__.py` in streamlit-ploty-events can really be any Python *.py file. There's nothing inherent special about it being in the `__init__.py`. I actually put all the code into a `control_charts.py` file. Instead of trying to explain here, I updated my answer significantly. I hope it helps.